# Make a phone call from a worklight application

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst, tel

We create a html code to make a phone call from inside a WL App using this

```
document.location.href = 'tel:'+ phoneNumber;
```

It seems to be working at first, that is, it launches the dialer, make the call, and when the phone call ends, it meant to come back to the WL app where it was, however it restarted the WL app from the beginning, starting it from the splash screen, which is not the desired behavior, as it is expect that right after the dialer finishes, it returns to the  WL app where it was before the dialer started.

Any idea on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if all the steps is necessary.. but here it goes.

1) declare your activity singleInstance android:launchMode="singleInstance"

2) add this code to your activity

```
private PhoneStateListener callListener;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    callListener = new EndCallListener();
    ...
}

private class EndCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private final String LOG_TAG = "EndCallListener";

    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
            // finish();
        }
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // wait for phone to go offhook (probably set a boolean flag) so
            // you know your app initiated the call.
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");
            isPhoneCalling = true;
        }
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            // when this state occurs, and your flag is set, restart your
            // app
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");
            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
                // run when class initial and phone call ended,
                // need detect flag from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");

                if (isPhoneCalling) {

                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "restart app");

                    // restart app
                    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                    getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                    // i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                    startActivity(i);

                    isPhoneCalling = false;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

3) in your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: Sorry missed the fact that WL is a cross platform dev framework. Not sure if this helps much if anything then?

Comment: Hi cYrixmorten. Indeed, I am looking for something neutral to take full advantage of the worklight platform. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it now, you are replacing the worklight app with the tel URL.  You need to launch the URL in its own window.

Use:

```
window.open("tel:5551212");
```

This will suspend the app, and launch the phone.  When you exit the phone, the app will resume.

Comment: I have tried both ways. Same result, the WL app do not resume, actually, it restarts.
 function doSomething2() {
  window.open('tel:+12101525572', '_self'); 
 }

Comment: _self is tricky, and depends on the whitelist. Use: doSomething2() { window.open('tel:+12101525572', '_blank'); }

Comment: I just tried with "_self" and that is also working for me.  The app runs in the background and when I exit the phone it resumes without restarting.  I suppose that it is possible that on a low resource handset, the OS may proactively shut down all other apps when the phone app is running.  Can you leave other apps open, make a call, and return to them w/o restarting them?  How do you exit the phone?